# If $\frac{\beta_i}{\alpha_i} \leq \frac{\beta_{i+1}}{\alpha_{i+1}}, \forall i$, what can we say about the sequence $\frac{\beta_i}{1-\alpha_i}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

For two sequences $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ in $\mathbb{R}_+$ that obey the property:
$$ \frac{\beta_i}{\alpha_i} \leq \frac{\beta_{i+1}}{\alpha_{i+1}}, \forall i \in \mathbb{Z}^+$$

can any information be gained about the sequence:

$$\frac{\beta_i}{1 - \alpha_i}$$

particularly about things like monotonicity w.r.t. $i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $c_i=\beta_i/\alpha_i$ and $d_i=\beta_i/(1-\alpha_i)$. Combining both we get

$$d_i=c_i\left(\frac{1}{1-\alpha_i}-1\right).$$

So, I think we should have further informations about the sequence $\alpha_i$.

Comment: Ya I don't think I have enough information to make any major conclusions about $d_i$. Thank you though :)